# use two files to create a third file

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk, sed

I need help to create a 3rd file based on data of two files. where both files have same number of record and data in each file corresponds to each other.

Fields.txt has data as below

```
Field1
DEST_1
TEMPS
FLAGS
```

Datatype.txt has data as below

```
INTEGER
CHAR
DATE
DATE
```

I need help with any script which will check the data type in datatype.txt file and if it matches with DATE will create 3rd file using the fields.txt and the corresponding field should be formated. I am expecting data in 3rd file as below

```
Field1
DEST_1
CHAR(TEMPS)
CHAR(FLAGS)
```

Above is an example there could be more data in source file, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask]. You are expected to make an effort to solve the problem yourself, show what you have tried, and explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR { type[NR] = $0; next }
        { print (type[FNR]=="DATE" ? "CHAR(" $0 ")" : $0) }
' datatype.txt fields.txt
Field1
DEST_1
CHAR(TEMPS)
CHAR(FLAGS)
```

Read the file `datatype.txt` in memory indexed at line number. While reading `fields.txt` file check if the array value is `DATE`. If it is replace the line with your desired output.

This requires to keep the file `datatype.txt` in memory. If the file is too big, there is an alternate way to read both file in parallel.

```
$ awk '
(getline type < "datatype.txt") > 0 {
    print (type=="DATE" ? "CHAR(" $0 ")" : $0)
}' fields.txt
Field1
DEST_1
CHAR(TEMPS)
CHAR(FLAGS)
```

This solution requires the use of `getline`. Please read the [offer document](http://awk.info/?tip/getline) carefully before investing.

Here is another way using `paste` and `awk` as suggested by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672254/use-two-files-to-create-a-third-file/25672911?noredirect=1#comment40121650_25672911) in the comments below.

```
$ paste datatype.txt fields.txt | awk '{ print ($1=="DATE" ? "CHAR(" $2 ")" : $2)}'
Field1
DEST_1
CHAR(TEMPS)
CHAR(FLAGS)
```

Comment: Interesting that you changed from `condition {x=y} print x` to `print (condition ? y : x)` for the getline version. Nothing wrong with either approach just interesting that you changed. FWIW if you MUST use getline, it's best to test it's result, so `awk '(getline type < "datatype.txt") > 0 {print...}`. Otherwise it could fail and leave `type` set to it's previous value and you'd get the expected number of lines output but with the last N lines corrupted and never know if you weren't paying close attention. I'd probably consider a `paste file1 file2 | awk` solution before getline but YMMV.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point, yea sorry I had to rush off in to a meeting so just wrote what ever came to my head first. `:P`. I will update the answer to include your suggestion. Thanks again!.

Comment: Thanks Guys, i am able to now get data a sexpected.
Appreciate it a lot. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Just [open](http://p3rl.org/open) both the files. Read them line by line ([readline](http://p3rl.org/readline)), if the line in the second file is "DATE" (don't forget to [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp)), output `"CHAR($line2)"`, otherwise output ([print](http://p3rl.org/print)) just `$line1`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the files in parallel:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#open my $fh1, '<', 'Fields.txt';
open my $fh1, '<', \ "Field1\nDEST_1\nTEMPS\nFLAGS\n";

#open my $fh2, '<', 'Datatype.txt';
open my $fh2, '<', \ "INTEGER\nCHAR\nDATE\nDATE\n";

while (!eof($fh1) && !eof($fh2)) {
    chomp(my $line1 = <$fh1>);
    chomp(my $line2 = <$fh2>);

    print $line2 eq 'DATE' ? "CHAR($line1)\n" : "$line1\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Field1
DEST_1
CHAR(TEMPS)
CHAR(FLAGS)
```